# How to turn off screen rotation in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, screen, gnome-shell, display-rotation

In Ubuntu 17.04 there was 'Rotation' menu in Display tab. But now in new version of Ubuntu, there's still a Display tab but no more rotation menu. Now I can't turn that off again since I upgraded to 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to use the icon that is available in the top right corner of the screen, when you click on the down arrow. The icon is the one in red in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot with the icon]

It might also look like this:

[image: screenshot with the icon on 19.3]

Comment: wow.. i had no clue what it was for until my display started rotating in bed

Comment: What an annoying pesky little feature that I'm not sure what anyone would actually use. Can anyone enlighten me? Why would you want automatic screen orientation on a PC?

Comment: I was sick of this rotation .. thanks for writing this.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're screen rotates before you sign in, it glitches out.

Comment: @Giszmo What is [19.3](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1036523/4)? Did you mean Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: Commenting the revision comment? Yeah, probably.

Comment: About, why you would use it, I bought my computer for this feature, I fold the keyboard behind the screen and turn it to portrait mode to read the newspaper every morning.

Comment: I figured it out but before login it seems that it forgets it on login screen. and it never shows enabled / disabled different in button. How can I know if this is enabled or disabled.

Comment: I am using 18.04 on my PC. I don't have the icon though. Can someone explain me why? Is it maybe because my PC doesn't have rotating sensors?

Comment: Thanks a mill. Works like a charm

Answer (score 44):

If you want to remove this feature then fire below commands :

**Try this command to stop and disable**

```
$ sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
$ sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

**Try this command to remove**

```
$ sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

Comment: Do the above and use settings / displays (or gnome tweak etc) to reset the rotation manually.

Comment: I am just removing those serveries. But in newer version on linux, this problem is gone.

Every Linux kernel from 4.3 up to version 4.12 had a bug that made made iio-sensor-proxy fail... 

Visit : https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy

Comment: I am on Pop!OS 19.10 and iio-sensor-proxy still has issues with HDAP sensors, thinking  it is an orientation accelerometer. If this is the case, remove iio-sensor-proxy and install something like:

```hdapsd - HDAPS daemon for various laptops with motion sensors```
or ```tp-smapi-dkms - ThinkPad hardware/firmware access modules source - dkms version ```

Comment: @Tech1337 I strongly suggest you.. Ask this same question in their forum. 
Btw, which kerner is currently running on 19.10 ? If this pop!OS based on ubuntu then, these issue shouldn't come...

Comment: I love this answer. some laptops have the sensor inside of them, not to rotate the screen but used for things like drop detection and what not. like my HP EliteBook 840. thank you for posting this, as it was the only thing that permanently fixed the issue

Comment: I can confirm this answer worked on `Ubuntu 22.04`.

Answer (score 17):

You may use the keyboard combination <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to toggle the rotation lock ON/OFF as described in [@Sylvain](https://askubuntu.com/users/830179/sylvain)'s answer.

[image: screenshot with the icon]

Note that <kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the key with Windows logo.

Answer (score 16):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
```

The above just worked for me. Seems the simplest solution

Comment: It seems to me that this simply changes the default toggle state of the icon the other answers mention (default state after boot). Which is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean "turn off screen rotation" ? Do you mean go back to normal orientation ?

Anyway, in the new gnome-control-center of gnome 3.28, in Devices > Screen Display tab, you can **click** on **Orientation** and a menu appears to let you choose between

```
- Landscape
- Portrait right
- Portrait left
- Landscape (flipped)
```

I guess this is what you want ?

Comment: This thread continues to be useful! Fixing my wife's HP-dv6 **laptop**'s upside-down screen, I found that the Devices > Screen > Orientation option menu only appears when iio-sensor-proxy.service is stopped, disabled, and (preferably) removed per shivangpatel -- and then the spurious 'orientation' icon in the upper-right corner of the Gnome desktop screen **disappears** !! And the gsettings commands per vaishaldhir were also helpful to make sure those settings were correct.Thanks, all, for the information!

Answer (score 3):

for me none of these work. As soon as I put the computer to sleep and wake it up again, it puts itself in the wrong orientation (due to the fact that the computer is sitting on a tilted support that raises it up). The only thing that I manage to do quickly is

> xrandr -o normal

to fall back to normal orientation. This is painful

Comment: sorry, removing iio-sensor-proxy does remove the problem of course.... But none of the proposed config fixes seem to hold after sleep/wake cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code given below and it will work.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock true
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
```

Comment: orientation-lock is the same as the `<Super>+o` control.

Comment: This is the most transportable answer, any other option to enable/disable affects this gnome setting.  To monitor this, see the output of `gsettings monitor org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock`.