# Laptop Screen Rotates Automatically

Tags: screen, 18.04, login-screen, display-rotation

Currently i am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Whenever i turn on my laptop after loading Ubuntu icon screen the screen rotates on User login screen even when laptop is not rotated. And it shows two cursors and from them the original cursor became vanish and only the mirrored cursor exist.
After logout and logging in again fixed this issue but it is very annoying and even i set screen rotation lock.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to blacklist the module in question, first, try to unload the module from your RAM.

```
sudo modprobe -r lis3lv02d
```

If it doesn't work, you can try to identify which module enable your motion sensor with the following command

```
sudo cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

Finally, if your blacklist command fixed the issue, make the change permanent with

```
editor /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And add the following line at the end of the file (probably empty)

```
blacklist lis3lv02d
```

Comment: That doesn't worked

Answer (score 1):

On a HP laptop (e.g. the EliteBook 840 G3 I have), you can instead remove the module `hp_accel`:

`sudo rmmod hp_accel`

This is better because usually lis31v02d will probably by "in use" - it's known as a "dependency". Because it's being used, you can't remove it, so the above suggestion removes the module that relies on it. The side effect of removing the "parent" module is that the "child" module is also removed.

Answer (score 1):

This feature hasn't been useful to me personally so I just remove it right away when I install Gnome.
If you want to remove this feature then fire below commands :

**Try this command to stop and disable**

```
$ sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
$ sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

**Try this command to remove**

```
$ sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

Curtosy : https://askubuntu.com/a/1059678/834205