# Ubuntu 18.04 Screen rotates on HP compaq 9420 when laptop is moved or bumped

Tags: 18.04, display, display-rotation

HP Compaq 9420 17" screen with Intel 2.16 core 2 duo 4gb ddr2 nvida graphics. How do I make the screen Stationary-Fixed?

I Installed Ubuntu 18.04 now at the slightest touch or bump the screen rotates. In the settings it says rotation 'Normal'. Is there a way to stop this screen from rotating?

It rolls out easily, but can be hard to get it back into the correct position. It never rotated with Ubuntu 16.04,  Maybe I should wait before changing from 16.04?

Comment: Does it have an orientation sensor? Does it rotate 90° or 180°?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035209/how-to-turn-off-screen-rotation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1036523#1036523 this solved my issue.