# automatic screen rotation problem on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

i have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my hp-pavilion-15-notebook-pc. my screen rotates itself again and again. i have searched in setting to get it right but i get no solution yet. help me guys.

Comment: Check this link - 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035209/how-to-turn-off-screen-rotation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts

or try this - 
$`xrandr -o normal`

Comment: would you please upvote, if my answer was useful? thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this to set it to normal

```
$ xrandr -o normal
```

But the **permanent solution** is to stop and disable the sensor on restart

```
$ sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service 
$ sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command, works for me -

```
$ xrandr -o normal
```

then logout and log back in or simply restart should work.