# Ubuntu always starts with the screen oriented sideways (tablet). How can I tell it (e.g. with xrandr) to always start normal for all users?

Tags: screen, xrandr, orientation

Update: so far the best solution I found is to add `xrandr -o normal` to ~.xinitrc.

Wonder why Ubuntu doesn't do this by default, and when I installed it before, I xrander'd before installing and it always did it automatically from there on, so I guess it built that setting into the system.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the orientation default in Settings/Screen Display? You could also read here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035209/how-to-turn-off-screen-rotation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts and if all else fails fry https://github.com/GuLinux/ScreenRotator