# How to turn on screen auto-rotation on Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: dell, 22.10

I bought a new Dell (P147G: Inspiron 7415) **2-in-1** laptop and installed Ubuntu **22.10**. While using the try  mode the screen auto-rotation was working excellent. But after installation this function disappeared. Finally, I am seeking to know, if there is any way to bring back the auto-rotation.

Comment: there should be a setting to toggle it in the drop-down menu that you get from clicking in the top-right corner, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035209/how-to-turn-off-screen-rotation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts. Is that setting there/enabled?